# What is the best way to access Google Play Developers API with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-play

There are only Python and Java client wrappers for `android-publisher` [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries) (used to verify IAP). With Node.js it seems like the only way is via http however, I was wondering if there is a way to use the [Google API Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) client to generate the authorization token for OAuth service-to-service authentication and pass it to the http call. Generating the JWT token by hand is an arduous and lengthy process. Is there a best practice / recommended way for doing this the easy way?

Answer (score 9):

Eldermao, just use google.auth.GoogleAuth to get the JWT client for authenticated with Google API. Here is the example from the google code :

```js
// Before running the sample:
// - Enable the API at:
//   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/androidpublisher.googleapis.com
// - Login into gcloud by running:
//   `$ gcloud auth application-default login`
// - Install the npm module by running:
//   `$ npm install googleapis`

const {google} = require('googleapis');
const androidpublisher = google.androidpublisher('v3');

async function main() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
  });

  // Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  google.options({auth: authClient});

  // Do the magic
  const res = await androidpublisher.purchases.subscriptions.get({
    // The package name of the application for which this subscription was purchased (for example, 'com.some.thing').
    packageName: 'placeholder-value',
    // The purchased subscription ID (for example, 'monthly001').
    subscriptionId: 'placeholder-value',
    // The token provided to the user's device when the subscription was purchased.
    token: 'placeholder-value',
  });
  console.log(res.data);

  // Example response
  // {
  //   "acknowledgementState": 0,
  //   "autoRenewing": false,
  //   "autoResumeTimeMillis": "my_autoResumeTimeMillis",
  //   "cancelReason": 0,
  //   "cancelSurveyResult": {},
  //   "countryCode": "my_countryCode",
  //   "developerPayload": "my_developerPayload",
  //   "emailAddress": "my_emailAddress",
  //   "expiryTimeMillis": "my_expiryTimeMillis",
  //   "externalAccountId": "my_externalAccountId",
  //   "familyName": "my_familyName",
  //   "givenName": "my_givenName",
  //   "introductoryPriceInfo": {},
  //   "kind": "my_kind",
  //   "linkedPurchaseToken": "my_linkedPurchaseToken",
  //   "obfuscatedExternalAccountId": "my_obfuscatedExternalAccountId",
  //   "obfuscatedExternalProfileId": "my_obfuscatedExternalProfileId",
  //   "orderId": "my_orderId",
  //   "paymentState": 0,
  //   "priceAmountMicros": "my_priceAmountMicros",
  //   "priceChange": {},
  //   "priceCurrencyCode": "my_priceCurrencyCode",
  //   "profileId": "my_profileId",
  //   "profileName": "my_profileName",
  //   "promotionCode": "my_promotionCode",
  //   "promotionType": 0,
  //   "purchaseType": 0,
  //   "startTimeMillis": "my_startTimeMillis",
  //   "userCancellationTimeMillis": "my_userCancellationTimeMillis"
  // }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I ended up using python to access the API and then I created a web service which I then access using node. In this way it would be much more straightforward, and I will use this approach next time. I think I was doing this to verify mobile payments.

Comment: If you use service account here is the additional parameter to pass in

```
const auth = new docs.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFilename: 'PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.json',
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis ?
It is the official library by Google.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: The library you suggest does not list the `android-publisher API` as part of their supported APIs.

Comment: at the line 9500 here : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/androidpublisher/v3.ts, you can find an example of how to use the android-publisher api